# Boolean Identities: the Distributive law

Tags: boolean-algebra

Need an explanation and solution for this...

In Boolean Identities, the Distributive law states that:

```
1. x (or) 1 = ?  
2. x (and) 0 = ?
```

How do I distribute this?

Comment: You don't.  These are the Anihilation Rules.

Comment: Do you mean annulment?

Comment: Annihilation is sometimes called that.

Comment: Ok thanks......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Closing question because this was a confusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhKun.png)